# sqlite data is not saved between iPhone app re to launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

When the app is running, I can create tables, insert and retrieve data from and to my sqlite database, but as soon as I relaunch the app, the database is empty again. Shouldn't the data be stored, until I specifically say "DROP..."

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but you don't have a lot of information here. My best guess is that you aren't saving your context which is handled by an instance method of NSManagedObjectContext.

```
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error;
```

Comment: I think NSManagedObjectContext belongs to CoreData, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Are you not using CoreData?